# Why do I get different outputs with \r escape sequence in different IDLE?

Tags: python

When is used the `\r` in sublime, it behaved as a `\n` escape sequence.

```
carriage_return = "I will use a carriage\rreturn" 
print (carriage_return)
```

> I will use a carriage
>
> return

But when I used it in the python 3.7.2 IDLE, the output was:

> I will use a carriagereturn

Why is there's a different output?
How do you use the `\r` escape sequence?

Answer (score 4):

A "carriage return" traditionally moved the cursor back to the beginning of the line so you should have seen the output as:

```
return use a carriage
```

because the `i will` would have been overwritten.

However, this tradition has now changed as standards have developed and there is no more uniform handling of a "carriage return". For example, HTML treats a `\r` as a whitespace.

Since I am new to *stackoverflow* please tell me how to improve my answer.

Comment: The only improvement I can suggest is to provide an actual solution. The only one I can think of is to use `\n` instead or `\r` consistently. As you note, there is no consistent handling of carriage return anymore.